# How to get the number of users in particular page of my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke-7

I have created an application in dnn 7.4 and i want your help can anyone give an idea,
How i can get the numbers of users using particular page or users there in that particular page of my website.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the real and accurate number of users currently viewing the page you need something holding a channel to the server or sending "ping of life" from the client to the server each second or so.
You may implement it alone using AJAX or you may use framework like SignalR - see these examples:

[Get the number of users that are online using SignalR](http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/get-the-number-of-users-that-are-online-using-signalr/1095)
[Tracking Online Users with SignalR](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/tracking-online-users-with-signalr/)

Answer (score 0):

you can just add static variable in the page.

```
  static int userCount= 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack())
            userCount++;
    }
```

Aspx code behind is nothing but IHttpHandler which is loaded when w3wp process is initiated...So static variable will be intialized as soon as class is loaded i.e. in this case when application starts and will be live throughout application scope

Note: The above coe will give you count of users visited the page..but you have to do something similar like that...On Page unload you can decrement static to variable to get current user on page

```
protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   userCount--;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but its will give the count of user visited that page.And i am looking for number of users currently there in that page.

Comment: when you say not working what is not working? are youg etting error or you are simply getting incorrect count? @AmritaVerma

Comment: every time count is coming one may be because of the Page_Unload method.Is anything i am missing?

Comment: ok..I know what is happening....to post more appropriate answer..need somemore info...can you use Jquery in your application?

Comment: the method `page_OnLoad` doesn't exist in ASP.NET

Comment: @Byyo I have not paid much attention on syntactical part of code...intention was to provide idea on how OP can achieve the functionality more than providing code which can be copy pasted....Thanks for letting me know of those error...

Comment: that won't work with a value stored in a `static int` you need to use application state and `Page_Unload` doesn't exist aswell